# How to configure spring security with Office 365 authentication?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm new to spring-security. I understood basics of spring-security about authentication-manager and other stuff.  
I'm using `angularjs` as front end, and `spring 3.0.5` as backend.

I want to add spring security for role based authorization to my existing project.

I also want to authenticate user using office 365. So, i created application in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and given redirect URI as my localhost action.

Using my code, I'm able to authenticate using office 365 and able to get username in redirected action.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCodeAndProcess", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    private ModelAndView getCodeAndProcess(@RequestParam("code") String code, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = null;
        try {
        session = request.getSession(false);
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(45*60);

        String username = helper.processCodeAndGetUsername(code); //this is I'm getting using office 365.
        String userRole = helper.getUserRoleBasedOnUsername(username);
        System.out.println("================userRole================="+userRole);
        if(username != "") {
            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            session.setAttribute("userRole", userRole);
        }else {
            session.invalidate();
            throw new Exception("username not found");
        }
       return new ModelAndView("redirect:/adminDashboard/showDashboard");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while processing on users authentication.",e );
        session.invalidate();
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login/loginPage");
    }
}
```

Now, I don't get how to configure username and roles in `security-context.xml`, so that i can use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` , `isAuthenticated()`, `<sec:authorize` in my application. (What to add in security-context.xml? So, that it bind username with role as it doing in form login scenario.)

Can you please help to understand this workflow?